# How to remove the panel on the right on my screen?

Tags: 11.04, panel, gnome

Since this morning, probably due to ubuntu or gnome-shell updates yesterday, I get this annoying panel on the right of my screen. It appears over my scrollbar, which makes it unusable. Has anybody else encountered this problem?

How can I remove it?

I guess there must be some setting in dconf-editor, but I don't know which one.

[image: extra but unwanted panel]

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. There was a dock-extension installed. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/dock-extension-for-gnome-shell/ states it should be installed in .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/, but in my case it was in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/. Removing the folder and reloading my desktop fixed the problem.

Comment: /usr/share is system-wide whereas /home/username/.local/share is personal. If you install from a package, then it is placed in /usr/share, since you're installing as root.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have Docky or AWN installed, drop them in Software Center (use search button for it)